# Checking both kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized and kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways constants

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, cllocationmanager, backwards-compatibility

I'm developing an app for iOS 7 and above, and I need to make use of the location services. When checking their authorization status, I found in the `CLLocationManager` related documentation that the `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorized` constant is deprecated in iOS 8.0, and that it equals the `kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways` for iOS 8.0 and later. Since I need to support iOS 7+, how could I handle the backwards compatibility when checking this status?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use
`[myLocationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]` 
to determin if the device is running iOS 8 and then ask for the desired level of permission